# How can I capture SCREEN_OFF/ON event when the app is idle?

Tags: android, android-event

For a proof of concept, I need to be able to capture whether the phone gets interactive, and the other way around.
So far, I tried following methods:

1. with BroadcastReceivers capturing SCREEN_OFF and SCREEN_ON events, but **this only works when the app is running**. If I try to add it to the manifest, I won't be able to capture the events if the app is not running (Android policies)
2. [Scheduling jobs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html). With this technique, Instead of suscribing to the events, I can check the status of the screen at the moment the job is running.
   Problem? for Nougat devices, the minimum periodic time I can specify for the job to run is **every 15 min**, which is too much for my proof of concept.

I haven't tried services yet, as I read in the documentation that this might not be the best way to do this. Quoting Android documentation:

> **You should avoid using started services that run perpetually or perform periodic work, since they continue to use device resources even when they are not performing useful tasks**. Instead, you should use other solutions that this page describes, and that provide native lifecycle management. Use started services only as a last resort. The Android platform may not support started services in the future

Am I looking at this the wrong way? Do you guys advice to go for the service (in this case, I would prefer to use background service).

Comment: you must put checks on activity lifecycles method to obtain its state. Your proposed idea is bit complex.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @killer, but I don't know what you mean with activity lifecycles. Can you please elaborate?